# How to fix poor sound and video quality when pairing YouTube with a television?

Tags: audio, video, youtube, video-streaming, miracast

I tried pairing the official Android YouTube app (by Google) with a television so I could watch a few videos on something larger.

I was surprised by the poor quality of the audio and video.

The audio sounded somewhat muffled compared to what is normal.  It was distracting enough that it made the experience less than desirable.

The video quality was poor as well.  When we speak of poor video quality we normally speak of low resolution or glitches.  However, the resolution looked adequate and there were no glitches.  Instead, everything seemed washed out, like someone turned the brightness on too high.

Between the poor audio quality and the video issues, I don't feel like this technology is ready for prime time.

Is there any way to fix these issues or make adjustments?

Comment: Perhaps you could share exactly what devices are involved here?

Comment: @acejavelin Definitely.  On the mobile side, I tried it on two KitKat devices.  The TV was a standard non-smart HDTV (nothing special, I can get the brand if it matters) with a Samsung sound bar.  Attached to the HDTV was an Amazon Fire Stick with the Google YouTube app installed on it.  Nothing else was using WiFi at the time, and the WiFi router was about 9 feet from all the devices with nothing physically in the way (no walls).  If any other details are helpful, let me know, and I'll do my best to get them.